# SelectedIndexChanged How it works

Tags: c#, asp.net

Friends I need some help..

I have 4 DropDownList in my project

I show you markup two of them..

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDwonList1" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="--Select Region--" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="HollyWood" Value="HollyWood"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="BollyWood" Value="BollyWood"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Farance" Value="Farance"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

DropDwonList2 is binded with DB

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDwonList2" runat="server" />
```

I want if i select HollyWood from DropDwonList1 the DropDwonList2 shows only hollywood actors name
if I select boolyWood DropDwonList2 shows only bollywood actors name.

```
public void BindDDL_ActorName_RegionOne()
{
    string query = "Select ID, Actor_Name from Actor where Region_Id=1";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
DropDwonList2.DataSource = dt;
DropDwonList2.DataTextField = "Name";
DropDwonList2.DataValueField = "ID";
DropDwonList2.DataBind();
DropDwonList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Name--"));
}

public void BindDDL_ActorName_RegionTwo()
{
    string query = "Select ID, Actor_Name from Actor where Region_Id=2";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
DropDwonList2.DataSource = dt;
DropDwonList2.DataTextField = "Name";
DropDwonList2.DataValueField = "ID";
DropDwonList2.DataBind();
DropDwonList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Name--"));
}

public void BindDDL_ActorName_RegionThree()
{
    string query = "Select ID, Actor_Name from Actor where Region_Id=3";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
DropDwonList2.DataSource = dt;
DropDwonList2.DataTextField = "Name";   
DropDwonList2.DataValueField = "ID";
DropDwonList2.DataBind();
DropDwonList2.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Name--"));
}
```

I found "SelectedIndexChanged" event to make this function active.
but I dont about this event I've never worked before now.

Kindly put some example with code so that i come to know how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You will need to add

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="Index_Changed"
AutoPostBack="true"
```

to your

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDwonList1" runat="server">
```

so it would look like

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDwonList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Index_Changed" AutoPostBack="true">
```

In your C# code you would add a function for this index change

```
protected void Index_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Put logic to figure out what needs to be selected
}
```

For that logic you could do something like

```
if(DropDwonList1.SelectedValue.Text.Equals("HollyWood")){
    BindDDL_ActorName_RegionOne();
}
```

and then obviously just write other if/else statements to finish out the remaining choices.

Comment: Also, you only need the autopostback when you want the selection to take place immediately. If you have a situation where you want to change multiple dropdowns and don't want the page reloading with each change just set it to false and have a button or some other element trigger the postback.